# How get all the descendants children of a div Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need get all the descendents children of a div en Jquery not only direct children
I need that the property css is applied both elements p  and elements span

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .descendants * {
      display: block;
      border: 2px solid lightgrey;
      color: lightgrey;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 15px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("div").children().css({
        "color": "red",
        "border": "2px solid red"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element)
    <p>p (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </p>
    <p>p (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `.children()` (which only gets...wait for it... the children of an element) use  `.find('*')`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").find('*').css({
    "color": "red",
    "border": "2px solid red"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="descendants" style="width:500px;">div (current element)
  <p>p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span> 
  </p>
  <p>p (child)
    <span>span (grandchild)</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer j08691 That is what I wanted

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div *").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
});
</script>
```

Edit: As per the comments clarification.

```
  $("div p").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
  $("div span").css({"color":"red","border":"2px solid red"});
```

Comment: I think he wanted the css only applied to `span` elements, didn't he? In any case, can you add an explanation along with your code sample?

Comment: I want the property applied a p and a span. The 2

Comment: I like this one. The css selector for all the children of divs is `"selector_for_div *"`, which is why it works. If he wanted the spans `"#my_div span"`